# QPython cannot install requests module

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, qpython3

Trying to install the requests module on QPython 3 using `pip install requests` gives me this error

[image: Error]
[pip.log](https://pastebin.com/4dh71VHY)

What is the cause of this error and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try manually downloading requests(http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install), extract the contents and copy it to your Lib/site-packages/Requests/ folder, from there python should be able to fetch the module.

Comment: It did not work for me. I do not have a 'Lib/site-packages/' folder, I have 'lib/python3.2/site-packages'. Placing the extracted content there did not allow me to import the module

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 1.4.x ? I thought it had solved the issue.